# Automatically create chapter breaks and titles from plain text file?

Tags: xml, epub, kindle, nook, calibre

I have a big file that is separated into categories with an underscore beneath each category name. The file is constantly changing and there are 80 categories. It is a plain text file. I would like to make it so that each category name is a separate chapter in an epub file. I would also like to make sure each chapter name is the title of the chapter. Is there a way to do this automatically with Calibre? Maybe some regex magic? For example, I would like the chapter titles for the categories below to be: Fruit, Vegetables, Herbs. And I would like it to be parsed automatically (one way to do this would probably involve recognizing the underscores in a regex expression). How can I do this?

```
Fruit
________
Apples
Bananas

Vegetables
____________
Cucumbers 
Zucchini

Herbs
_____
thyme
cayenne
```

Answer (score 4):

So your text file is basically an almost `markdown` file ([read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)). I would convert it to `html` with something like `pandoc` ([see here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), and note that pandoc supports some extended `markdown` features, and is very capable (even can generate epub too, but I did not tested that yet)).

That way your headers (the underlined lines) would be translated to `<h*>` tags.

Then you can use for example Calibre's ebook-convert CLI tool (or the gui) to convert it to `mobi` or `epub`, and specify the chapter breaks (thanks to the developers, Calibre [has a really good documentation](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html)). (And I just noticed, that Calibre/ebook-convert can convert markdown directly to epub/mobi!)

Like:

```
ebook-convert input.html output.epub --chapter 'YOUR XPATH TO DETECT CHAPTERS' --chapter-mark pagebreak
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. Your file is already like markdown; all you need to do is change extension to `.md` (but you do not have to - see below).

So the first heading underlined is level one and the next subsequent headings with the same type of underline will also be level one. When you start using a different line for the first time, that will be level two, etc.

I personally prefer to start heading 1 with # heading 2 with ## etc.

generating `.epub` takes a second with `pandoc`; a sample command is below:

```
pandoc myTextFile.md --latex-engine=xelatex -o myEpubFile.epub
```

I use xelatex engine because of some unicode characters expected in text, but if it is plain English(ASCII) - you don't need to. Just like that you can also produce `.PDF` and `.docx` formats in seconds.

If you would like to keep your input file extension `.txt` that is not a problem; just specify `--from markdown` on command line and the input will be read as markdown regardless of what the file extension is. Of course - a binary format like `.docx` can't be read that way, but then yo will get an error message.

What I like about this method is that it is lightning quick, adjustable and does not require me to open calibre.

Pandoc defaults also start new chapter with each level 1 heading. You can adjust it via parameter `--epub-chapter-level`.